# Convert Hex value to ASCII character from array and how to eliminate null value?

Tags: java, arrays, null

I'm in the middle trying to convert the hex value that I retrieved from my method, compareHexaRGB to ASCII character which I want to know what output is going to produce. I don't know if I'm doing it wrong or I missed to code somewhere.

Code for extractMessage() method to convert hex value to ASCII:

```
public class extractMessage
{
private static String[][] char1;
private static String[][] char2;
private static String[][] in;
private static String[][] combine;


public static void extractMessage(String[][] inn, String[][] comb)
{
    in = inn;
    combine = comb;
}

public static void printString2DArray(String[][] in) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < in.length; i++) 
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < in[i].length; j++)
        {
            System.out.println(in[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public static void charExtract()
{
    compareHexaRGB hexRGB = new compareHexaRGB();

    char1 = hexRGB.getCheck_hex2();
    char2 = hexRGB.getCheck_hex4();

    combine = new String[char1.length][char1[0].length];

    for(int i = 0; i < char1.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < char1[i].length; j++)
        {
            //concatenate string
            combine[i][j] = char1[i][j] + char2[i][j];
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Char 1 + Char 2: ");
    printString2DArray(combine);
}

public static String convertHexToString()
{
    extractMessage em = new extractMessage();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();

    String out = em.charExtract(); //error stated incompatible types: void cannot be converted to String

    int decimal;

    for(int i = 0; i < out.length(); i += 2)
    {
        String output = out.substring(i, (i + 2));
        decimal = Integer.parseInt(output, 16);
        sb.append((char)decimal);

        temp.append(decimal);
    }
    System.out.println("Output: " + temp.toString());
    return sb.toString();
}
}
```

Second, I still cannot eliminate the NULL value from the retrieved value. Someone said I need to add a place to hold the characters which in this case the NULL value. I've done that but when I try to run the code then, here we go again, the nullpointerexception occur. I'm still new to java and lack of experience handling with java arrays and advanced java but I'm eager to learn. Java is very interesting language and I hope one day I could master on this language.

Code for compareHexaRGB() :

```
public class compareHexaRGB
{
private static int w;
private static int h;
private static BufferedImage img;
private static BufferedImage img2;
private static String[][] check_hex2;
private static String[][] check_hex4;
private static String[][] not_stega2;
private static String[][] not_stega4;

public static void compareHexaRGB(BufferedImage image, BufferedImage image2, int width, int height) throws IOException 
{
    w = width;
    h = height;
    img = image;
    img2 = image2;

}

public void check() throws IOException
    {
        getPixelRGB1 pixel = new getPixelRGB1();
        getPixelData1 newPD = new getPixelData1();

        int[] rgb;
        int count = 0;

        int[][] pixelData = new int[w * h][3];
        check_hex2 = new String[w][h];
        check_hex4 = new String[w][h];

        for(int i = 0; i < w; i++) 
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < h; j++)
            {
                rgb = newPD.getPixelData(img, i, j);

                for(int k = 0; k < rgb.length; k++)
                {
                    pixelData[count][k] = rgb[k];
                }

                    if(pixel.display_imgHex2()[i][j].equals(pixel.display_img2Hex2()[i][j]))
                    {
                        System.out.println("\nPixel values at position 2 are the same." + "\n" + pixel.display_imgHex2()[i][j] + "  " + pixel.display_img2Hex2()[i][j]);
                        not_stega2[i][j] = pixel.display_img2Hex2()[i][j]; // i've done the same as check_hex2 and check_hex4 method but why the error still occur?
                    }
                    if(pixel.display_imgHex4()[i][j].equals(pixel.display_img2Hex4()[i][j]))
                    {
                        System.out.println("\nPixel values at position 4 are the same." + "\n" + pixel.display_imgHex4()[i][j] + "  " + pixel.display_img2Hex4()[i][j]);
                        not_stega4[i][j] = pixel.display_img2Hex4()[i][j];
                    }
                    if(!pixel.display_imgHex2()[i][j].equals(pixel.display_img2Hex2()[i][j]))
                    {
                        System.out.println("\nPixel values at position 2 are not the same." + "\n" + pixel.display_imgHex2()[i][j] + "  " + pixel.display_img2Hex2()[i][j]);
                        check_hex2[i][j] = pixel.display_img2Hex2()[i][j];
                        System.out.println("\nOutput Hex 2: " + check_hex2[i][j]);
                    }
                    if(!pixel.display_imgHex4()[i][j].equals(pixel.display_img2Hex4()[i][j]))
                    {
                        System.out.println("\nPixel values at position 4 are not the same." + "\n" + pixel.display_imgHex4()[i][j] + "  " + pixel.display_img2Hex4()[i][j]);
                        check_hex4[i][j] = pixel.display_img2Hex4()[i][j];
                        System.out.println("\nOutput Hex 4: " + check_hex4[i][j]);
                    }
                    if(!pixel.display_imgHex2()[i][j].equals(pixel.display_img2Hex2()[i][j]) || (!pixel.display_imgHex4()[i][j].equals(pixel.display_img2Hex4()[i][j])))
                    {
                        System.out.println("\nOne of the pixel values at position 2 and 4 are not the same." + "\n" + pixel.display_imgHex2()[i][j] + "  " + pixel.display_img2Hex2()[i][j] + "\n" + pixel.display_imgHex4()[i][j] + "  " + pixel.display_img2Hex4()[i][j]);

                        if(!pixel.display_imgHex2()[i][j].equals(pixel.display_img2Hex2()[i][j]) || (pixel.display_imgHex2()[i][j].equals(pixel.display_img2Hex2()[i][j])))
                        {
                            check_hex2[i][j] = pixel.display_img2Hex2()[i][j];
                            System.out.println("\nOutput Hex 2: " + check_hex2[i][j]);
                        }

                        if(!pixel.display_imgHex4()[i][j].equals(pixel.display_img2Hex4()[i][j]) || (pixel.display_imgHex4()[i][j].equals(pixel.display_img2Hex4()[i][j])))
                        {
                            check_hex4[i][j] = pixel.display_img2Hex4()[i][j];
                            System.out.println("\nOutput Hex 4: " + check_hex4[i][j]);
                        }

                    }
                count++;
                System.out.println("\nOutput Count: " + count);
            }

        }

    }

public String[][] getCheck_hex2()
{
    return check_hex2;
}

public String[][] getCheck_hex4()
{
    return check_hex4;
}

public String[][] getCheck_notStega2()
{
    return not_stega2;
}

public String[][] getCheck_notStega4()
{
    return not_stega4;
}
 }
```

Hoping to eliminate these problems fast. Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i see there are 2 flaws in your code::

**1.** If charExtract() method is static then you need to access it in a static way as::

```
String out = extractMessage.charExtract();
```

**2.** Secondly as you are storing the value from charExtract() to a String variable "out"
so you need to return a string from the charExtract() method ,Declare it as

```
public static String charExtract()
{ ...
}
```

and return some value from charExtract like:

```
return combine[o][1];
```

Comment: thank you! now there are no errors. but when I run the coding, the nullpointerexception still occur. i guess the problem is in my compareHexaRGB() method. can you help?

Comment: @user3116040 If a answer helped you to rectify your problems then try voting up the post and accept it,because we all are not simply sitting here answering questions or else getting $$.

Comment: anyway, what is the nullpointerexception actually? is it something i code and i point it to null value? i need to clarify that in order to understand better java. thanks

Comment: if you are using a varible somewhere for which the value is null or say nothing,so the compiler will throw the null pointer exception.

Comment: and if you are running the program in eclipse or any othe IDE try debugging the code,you will get the exact code line because of which you are getting nullpointerexception..

Comment: but in my situation, i would like to store the unnecessary pixel value to another variable. so that the extraction method would not retrieve the null value too. i did that (store array to new variable) the same way as the difference pixel values which i want to examine that later in the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void charExtract()
{ ...
}
```

and

```
String out = em.charExtract(); //error stated incompatible types
```

obviously don't match. Besides, why are you trying to call the static method `charExtract()` upon the *instance* `em`?

What do you store in those `String[][]` arrays?

```
char1 = hexRGB.getCheck_hex2();
char2 = hexRGB.getCheck_hex4();
```

Without knowing what they are supposed to contain, we cannot help you convert their content to anything.

At the moment I assume that you don't really want to deal with "hex" numbers; calculations are much easier performed on `int`s than on any String representation of numbers.

Comment: I want to analyze RGB pixel values on two similar images to see if one of them has different hex value at position 2 and 4. after detecting the differences, i would like to retrieve the value difference from image and combine it to one hex value. then convert it to ASCII. is that answer your question? i hope you could understand my situation.